# Installed Cuda toolkit 7.5, but libcudart.so.5.5 remains

Tags: drivers, apt, compiling, cuda, ld

After installing Cuda Toolkit 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 (via apt-get of .deb file, followed by update of nvidia driver to 352.63), nvcc --version, NVidia-smi, and cuda samples work as expected.

7.5 is installed in `/usr/local/cuda-7.5`, with `/usr/local/cuda` soft-linked to that location.

The file `/etc/profile.d/cuda-7-5.sh` contains just the line:

```
PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
```

And both `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda-7-5.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda-7-5.sh` contain just the line:

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

However, the system still contains `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.5.5`.

Questions:

1. Why is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.5.5` still present?  Is it required, or can it be removed?  What are the steps for removing it, and will 7.5 need to be reinstalled?
2. Are the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda-7-5.sh` correct, or should it be as follows?:

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```